Realm objects not being recognised. How to connect MongoDB Realm to a Kotlin Android studio project?
I am still new to kotlin and I've been trying to set up MongoDB Realm for my project and I am not sure what's wrong. I have set up the dependencies , I don't have any build errors however when I try to make a realm class such as for example the one below it does not recognise 'EmbeddedRealmObject', 'realmListOf' or 'backlinks' :
class Address : EmbeddedRealmObject {

    var fullName: String = ""
    var street: String = ""
    var houseNumber: Int = 0
    var zip: Int = 0
    var city: String = ""
    var teacher: Teacher ? = null
}

libs.versions library:
[versions]
agp = "8.4.1"
kotlin = "1.9.0"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.2.0"
espressoCore = "3.6.0"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.8.2"
activityCompose = "1.9.0"
composeBom = "2023.08.00"
org-jetbrains-kotlin-android = "1.8.0"
realmGradlePlugin = "10.17.0"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
androidx-ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
androidx-ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
androidx-ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
androidx-ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
androidx-ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
androidx-ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
realm-gradle-plugin = { module = "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "realmGradlePlugin" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
org-jetbrains-kotlin-kapt = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt", version.ref = "org-jetbrains-kotlin-android" }

build.gradle.kts (project):
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt) apply false
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(libs.realm.gradle.plugin)
    }
}

build.gradle.kts (module):
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt)
    id("realm-android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.ebookfrenzy.kotlin_crud_app"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.ebookfrenzy.kotlin_crud_app"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)


    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}

settings.gradle.kts:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Kotlin-crud-app"
include(":app")
 

I have looked through tutorials such as this one to set up realm: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S58qPxdRW3c&t=920s , swell as followed this advice on set up from the mongodb community: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-use-realm-gradle-plugin-with-version-catalogs/267376 , but neither worked.
